# Docker container running on Linode server unable to connect to mongo atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect the node in Docker container which is running on my Linode server. I'm getting the following error.

**MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/**

If I run the same image in my local system everything works fine. DB connection is successfully establishing.

I added the docker IP address in the atlas cluster as whitelisted.
I added my server IP address in the atlas cluster as whitelisted.

I used the below command to get the Ip of my docker container.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <containerId>
```

Even after adding the IP of the container DB connection is throwing the error.

Since I'm new to docker Please let me know if I'm missing any steps in between or doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with "I added the docker IP address in the atlas cluster as whitelisted."? from your description it looks like you have at least 2 separate servers: an instance with docker and at least an instance with the atlas cluster. is it correct?

Comment: the "docker IP address" is in a private network and cannot be really seen by the atlas cluster. If that's the case, you should remove the docker ip address and whitelist the server ip instead.

Comment: I added my server IP to the whitelist, it didn't work so I added docker IP as well

Comment: I have only one server and inside the server docker node container is running

Comment: Check firewall rules on your server. Try to localize the problem, e.g. spin up a free EC2 box, run something like  `netcat -l 27017` there and point mongo connection to the mock. Try to run your docker and check if you have anything on netcat.  If you do, the connection is blocked on Atlas side. Otherwise the problem is on your system.

Comment: @Alex Blex Thanks I'll try this